# VisualAssist can't find declaration of boost::bind

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-assist

It's not programming question per se. But do you guys know how to make VisualAssist (v10.7.1916.0) parse declaration of boost::bind (v1.51) correctly ? It's currently always underlined with red in my code. Perhaps all those templates in `bind/bind_mf_cc.hpp` drive it crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Assist X does have problem dealing with complex c++ template such as boost headers. I encounter this very often. I suggest you disable the error underlining in VAX.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code compile? if `#include <bind/bin_mf_cc.hpp>` is in your file, and the path of the boost library is added in the include paths of the compiler, then Visual AssistX should automatically parse it...